# How to set dynamic template reference variable and access in angular 14

Tags: angular

Trying to change the object array value using template reference variable, But not working. So, How to set the dynamic template reference variable and how to access it? In my application i am trying to change the allData object values like selected is true for particular dropdown(Bus and Cycle). from main.component.ts. It is not working. How to resolve this issue?

main.component.ts:

```
  changeVal(veh) {  
  if(veh == this.userElements){
  this.userElements.allData.forEach((value, i) => {
  this.userElements.allData[i].selected = true;
  });
  }  
  }
```

main.component.html:

```
<div class="custom-select" style="width:400px;" *ngFor="let v of vehicle; index as i">
 <p>{{ v }}</p>
 <app-vehicle [data]="travals[v]" #[{{v}}]></app-vehicle>
 </div> 
 <button (click)="changeVal('Cycle')">Change Cycle object values</button> 
 <button (click)="changeVal('Bus')">Change Bus object values</button>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m5h5wx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.html

Comment: @DariuszOstolski: Just i am trying to change the allData values from main.component.ts

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but you can look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-437cb9?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/main/main.component.ts it will modify all data property but this is just one part the other part is to reflect it in dropdown. What I would suggest is to go through one of Angular courses on Udemy as well as Angular documentation on ViewChildren and QueryList. In my opinion you should be able to achieve what you want in a much cleaner way.

Comment: Improved stackblitz to what I suspect you want to achieve: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-437cb9?file=src/app/shared/vehicle/vehicle.component.html